# I purchased a Novatron 1000 vr set of 4 strobes

Tags: canon, portrait, studio-lighting

[trigger?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqeWy.jpg)In the set up that I purchased there is a gadget that I can’t figure out what it is. This is the gadget I’m gonna take a photograph.
On the head, do you know Novatron 1000 VR head there is a plug receptacle labeled sync do I plug this cable into that to sync my Canon 6D to the flash?[image]

Answer (score 2):

That gadget is an optical slave trigger. They come in various sizes and shapes. They also use various types of connections. Yours uses the standard “household” (HH)  electrical connection. Don’t plug it into the wall. It is meant to be connected to the flash trigger circuit. Flash units typically use use PC connectors, 1/4” plugs, or “household”(HH) blade connectors, but there have been many other types over the years.

You can connect the “sync” port on your flash to your 6D, using a “household” to PC adapter. You can also connect the optical slave to the flash and then use another flash on your 6D to trigger the slave.

[Flashzebra HH to PC sync cord](https://flashzebra.com/products/0239/index.shtml)
[image]